# Whys does bower itself show 0 dependency?

Tags: node.js, npm, bower, node-modules

On npm package search, bower shows 0 dependencies. https://www.npmjs.com/package/bower

However, if you install bower using `npm install bower`. There will be node_modules directoy under the bower/lib directory, which turns out to have some other npm packages installed there.

Is it cheating for bower to claim that it has 0 dependency since it actually uses external node packages?

Comment: I don't know if there's any cheating going on, but it's definitely incorrect: https://github.com/bower/bower/blob/master/package.json#L17

Answer (score 0):

It's all about package.json file dependencies section in bower module, if they mentioned any other modules so it will be viewed in npm site as dependency, if you checked GitHub repo for bower [Gruntfile.js](https://github.com/bower/bower/blob/master/Gruntfile.js) they are packing all models and deleting dependencies from package.json

```
        delete jsonPackage.dependencies;
        delete jsonPackage.devDependencies;
        delete jsonPackage.scripts;

        fs.writeFileSync(
            path.resolve(dir, 'package.json'),
            JSON.stringify(jsonPackage, null, '  ') + '\n'
        );

        grunt.log.writeln('Moving node_modules to lib directory...');

        wrench.copyDirSyncRecursive(
            path.resolve(dir, 'node_modules'),
            path.resolve(dir, 'lib', 'node_modules')
        );
```